# Python: how to search for a string in another string and make case transformation in the string being searched?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string as ,

```
subject_codes = "PTAQIFAIIAMRDGRVYLHPSNTPSTOPGCCRCRVFTLLRLPSGTFDESTTGWEKTSSLYHPGGNHTSTVSWWTILRKAAMGTGRLLLDEKEETPSTOPSCTHEVLGPTARCCSTOPYPIDEVNSTOPAFSTNRGCHQCCRRQFGVLGPHYVPSRREGKCKHLSTOPGLSPKDVLCWYFQSRPSGGSTOPLEELLPISVSPICSTOPNGGHRWEAYYQSTOPDQHLQETPWSLYLQEPGLIFQIIPDSWPPTLNTSISLYGEAMSTOPGEISSTOPEVSTOPGSCDFPSRSEGVTSQSTOPDGRGRLLHRSTOPKVPPLSCPTSTOPCRTFFHSTOPSTOPFGRLSTOPVLHLRRRECLRRSNINDSTOPGTREEVRYHGGDDPLGVYPTQYRPRNLEISLQGYPHSRRFLPSTOPTSYFRFSSTOPGTTWSHEGPSTOPRSHRSPTHVCCLEEKCPSTYGTLSTOPHSGSTOPNGQSTOPSPYRHCGSSMAADPAGTFGAHFKTHDVESPICVLQFSSAGSSLDGGHNDLQVQVVELRRSSILRFEGRDECSRYHLDSSPRETIPKGLWSTTKSLRSTOPLRNRSYWTSTOPRDRPPDGTTYSLAQRYHDGGTHGEAMSHSLEPLCGVLRVAQIQSSTOPVSTOPPGEPPSEALPYWGRSTOPSLSGRSPALSSTOPLYDKVPSSIWVPDRGWSTWYFPYSGTLRGESTVHREFLEEETPSTOPSQELSRIDDCGDHKGQNSSTOPTRISTSYYQRSTOPSTOPECCHRQVLDDISLFEVDAKTPTVARMAQTDDKRPIRVTNGGMATESPETSEVFQSTOPHHASQILRGLWLSHVRPRGIYGLYKSLPTIAVDYRRSLSTOPRPSTMEGRDQRTFPVKPEPLEERRHSTOPVSKVRTRHHSTOPTTHDGLESTOPSSELEATRREVSISSWSTRDSSRGPTGGLHVHKTICRSTOPGDTRCHFPKLSFGASSTOPDLQFQHSALSTOPKNYGDCVGKTGGPWHSTOPSTOPMLANLRFRRVSINEGSTOPSKRRFLLSTOPHPRDYLCRYRVLGPGSTOPSGDSTOPDLGVHSTOPCSTOPFSTOPETIHHESSNSQNSRSTOPIPLPFEESTOPRAILWGVQRTGHGSYGTGDIMSSTOPSPPVTTWLDYLFGFCRRRVPKEFHRQHHASEPTAQI"
```

and a list of substrings as

```
category_codes = ["MRDGRVYLHPSNTPSTOP","MGTGRLLLDEKEETPSTOP","MSTOP","MAADPAGTFGAHFKTHDVESPICVLQFSSAGSSLDGGHNDLQVQVVELRRSSILRFEGRDECSRYHLDSSPRETIPKGLWSTTKSLRSTOP","MSHSLEPLCGVLRVAQIQSSTOP","MATESPETSEVFQSTOP","MAQTDDKRPIRVTNGGMATESPETSEVFQSTOP","MEGRDQRTFPVKPEPLEERRHSTOP","MLANLRFRRVSINEGSTOP","MSSTOP"]
```

I want to search for the substrings from the list in the bigger string, and have the matching cases changed to lower-case in the bigger string itself. I know how to search for a string in another using the `find()` method, but I'm not able to think through how to best have the matching substrings replaced in the bigger string. I'm looking for a cleaner and computationally efficient way of doing this.

The desired output string should be like this,

```
output = "PTAQIFAIIAmrdgrvylhpsntppstopGCCRCRVFTLLRLPSGTFDESTTGWEKTSSLYHPGGNHTSTVSWWTILRKAAMGTGRLL...."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex by creating an alternative group from the second list

```
s = '|'.join(category_codes)
res = re.sub(s, lambda x: x.group(0).lower(), subject_codes)
```

Comment: why the '(' and '|' when converting list objects to single string ?

Comment: `(a|b) means find 'a' or 'b'

Comment: in this case, the brackets are even extra

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the split() method:

```
for category in category_codes:
    tmp_list = subject_codes.split(category, -1)
    category.lower().join(tmp_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but not very performant and computationally inefficient:

```
for cc in category_codes:
    subject_codes = subject_codes.replace(cc, cc.lower())
```